# cross compiling ndn-cxx for arduino yun

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, cross-compiling, waf, arduino-yun

I'm trying to cross compile ndn-cxx on ubuntu 16.10 to use it on arduino yun. I'm following this [steps](https://redmine.named-data.net/projects/ndn-embedded/wiki/Cross-compiling_NDN_projects_for_home_routers).
When I try to execute ./waf command I get the following error:

```
    [ 30/141] Compiling src/security/sec-public-info-sqlite3.cpp
mips-openwrt-linux-musl-g++: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined
cc1plus: error: one or more PCH files were found, but they were invalid
cc1plus: error: use -Winvalid-pch for more information
cc1plus: fatal error: /home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build/ndn-cxx.2: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'ndn-cxx' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 140640709384528: cxx sec-public-info-sqlite3.cpp -> sec-public-info-sqlite3.cpp.2.o}
['/home/andrea/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-5.3.0_musl-1.1.16/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-musl-g++', '-std=c++11', '-O2', '-fPIC', '-include', '/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build/ndn-cxx.2', '-I/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build', '-I/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1', '-I/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build/src', '-I/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/src', '-I/home/andrea/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_musl-1.1.16/usr/include', '-DNDEBUG', '../src/security/sec-public-info-sqlite3.cpp', '-c', '-o', '/home/andrea/ndn-cxx-ndn-cxx-0.4.1/build/src/security/sec-public-info-sqlite3.cpp.2.o']
```

the file ndn-cxx.2 is in the showed directory and its named ndn-cxx.2.gch.
Can you help me to find the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

More NDN developers will see your question on the ndn-lib list.
http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/mailman/listinfo/ndn-lib